# Stricter term for webification

Tags: terminology

Is there a special software engineering term for re-engineering and deploying a standalone desktop client as a website/web service

Answer (score 1):

I would call it *porting* to HTML5 or similar.  For instance, you often build an app for iOS and then port it to Android.  The web is just another platform these days.

Comment: Porting is a good one, I'm just not sure if it writing "porting application A to the web" is a good way of phrasing it. Was thinking either that or redeployment of application A as a web service. Will keep this question open for now to get more input.

Comment: Here is an example of someone using the phrase for Doom.  http://games.slashdot.org/story/11/05/31/1833239/Doom-Ported-To-the-Web